# How to update File metadata in Sharepoint CSOM?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I know this question has been asked in the past, but I can't seem to find a working solution.
I want to update The CreatedDateTime, ModifiedBy and CreatedBy metadata on a file that I uploaded with CSOM. I have this code. It does not crash, but does not update the properties either.

```
            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            byte[] FileContent = null;
           
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
                FileContent = webClient.DownloadData(file.DowlnloadUrl);
            }

            newFile.ContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileContent);
            newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Name);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sharepointFile = _spFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
            _context.ExecuteQuery();

            sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields["Modified"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
            sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields["Created"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
            sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
            _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The file still appears that it was created/modified a few seconds ago.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. ***PS:*** if this can be done ***in one go*** (one single ExecuteQuery), that would be great.

Comment: Try converting the datetime to short date string - `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3).ToShortDateString()` . You can try to execute query just once at the end.

Comment: Tried that and it is still not working. Do you think this is related to Versioning?

Comment: Would you have a code snippet that works? This is frustrating. I am pretty sure it used to work before. Not sure what I am missing out.

Comment: By the way, adding sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "Test" works. Other fields arent updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a code snippet that works.
Beware, this works only if the account your are using to generate the context is a **Sharepoint Admin** (has the SP admin role, and not only a Global Admin role).
Being an owner of the site does not suffice either.

Code can be found here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/update-a-sharepoint-listitem-without-increasing-its-item-file-version-using-sharepoint-client-side-modelcsom